# Not unique table/alias: 'ospos_people'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please help me for the below problem.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'ospos_people'

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, invoice_number, amount_tendered, sale_time, 
DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date, ospos_sales.sale_id AS 
sale_id, SUM(item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * (1 - discount_percent / 100)) 
AS amount_due FROM (ospos_sales) LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id 
= ospos_sales.customer_id LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = 
ospos_sales.vehicle_id JOIN ospos_sales_items ON ospos_sales_items.sale_id = 
ospos_sales.sale_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS 
amount_tendered FROM ospos_sales_payments WHERE payment_type <> 'Check' GROUP BY 
sale_id) AS payments ON payments.sale_id = ospos_sales.sale_id GROUP BY sale_id 
ORDER BY sale_time desc LIMIT 25
```

Filename: /home/../public_html/../models/sale.php

---

Model = sale.php

```
<?php
class Sale extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_info($sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, email, comment, invoice_number, amount_tendered, ' .
                 'sale_time, employee_id, customer_id, vehicle_id, comments');
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date", FALSE);
        $this->db->select("sales.sale_id AS sale_id");
        $this->db->select("SUM(item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * (1 - discount_percent / 100)) AS amount_due");
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.customer_id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.vehicle_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('sales_items', 'sales_items.sale_id = sales.sale_id');
        $this->db->join("(SELECT sale_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS amount_tendered " .
                " FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments') ." WHERE payment_type <> '" .
                $this->lang->line('sales_check') . "' GROUP BY sale_id) AS payments",
                "payments.sale_id = sales.sale_id", 'left');
        $this->db->where('sales.sale_id',$sale_id);
        $this->db->order_by('sale_time', 'desc');
        $this->db->group_by('sale_id');
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function get_all($only_invoices = 0, $rows = 0, $limit_from = 0)
    {
        $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, invoice_number, amount_tendered, sale_time');
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date", FALSE);
        $this->db->select("sales.sale_id AS sale_id");  
        $this->db->select("SUM(item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * (1 - discount_percent / 100)) AS amount_due");
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.customer_id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.vehicle_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('sales_items', 'sales_items.sale_id = sales.sale_id');
        $this->db->join("(SELECT sale_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS amount_tendered " .
                " FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments') ." WHERE payment_type <> '" . 
                $this->lang->line('sales_check') . "' GROUP BY sale_id) AS payments",
                "payments.sale_id = sales.sale_id", 'left');
        $this->db->order_by('sale_time', 'desc');
        $this->db->group_by('sale_id');
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $this->db->limit($rows, $limit_from);
        }
        if ($only_invoices != 0) {
            $this->db->where('invoice_number <> ', 'NULL');
        }
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function search($search, $only_invoices = FALSE, $rows = 0, $limit_from = 0) 
    {
        $valid_receipt = $this->sale_lib->is_valid_receipt($search);
        $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, invoice_number, amount_tendered, sale_time');
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date", FALSE);
        $this->db->select("sales.sale_id AS sale_id");
        $this->db->select("SUM(item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * (1 - discount_percent / 100)) AS amount_due");
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.customer_id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.vehicle_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('sales_items', 'sales_items.sale_id = sales.sale_id');
        $this->db->join("(SELECT sale_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS amount_tendered " .
                " FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments') ." WHERE payment_type <> '" . 
                $this->lang->line('sales_check') . "' GROUP BY sale_id) AS payments",
                "payments.sale_id = sales.sale_id", 'left');
        $this->db->group_by('sale_id');
        if (!empty($search)) {
            // if barcode scanned, explode and search for second term which will be the id
            if ($valid_receipt) {
                $pieces = explode(' ',$search);
                $this->db->where('sales.sale_id', $pieces[1]);
            } else {
                // open parentheses
                $this->db->where("( last_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR ".
                        "first_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR " .
                        "CONCAT( first_name,' ',last_name ) LIKE '%" . $search . "%')");
                // close parentheses
            }
        }
        if ($only_invoices != 0) {
            $this->db->where('invoice_number <> ', 'NULL');
        }
        $this->db->order_by('sale_time DESC');
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $this->db->limit($rows, $limit_from);
        }
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function get_total_rows()
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    function get_search_suggestions($search,$limit=25)
    {
        $suggestions = array();

        if (!$this->sale_lib->is_valid_receipt($search)) {
            $this->db->distinct();
            $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, invoice_number, sale_time');
            $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date", FALSE);
            $this->db->select("sales.sale_id AS sale_id");
            $this->db->from('sales');
            $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.customer_id', 'left');
                        $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.vehicle_id', 'left');
            $this->db->where("( last_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR ".
                    "first_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR " .
                    "CONCAT( first_name, last_name ))");
            $this->db->order_by('last_name', "asc");

            foreach($this->db->get()->result_array() as $result)
            {
                $suggestions[]=$result[ 'first_name' ].' '.$result[ 'last_name' ];
            }

        } else {
            $suggestions[]=$search;
        }
        return $suggestions;
    }

    function get_found_rows($search, $only_invoices = FALSE)
    {
        $valid_receipt = $this->sale_lib->is_valid_receipt($search);
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->join('sales_items', 'sales_items.sale_id = sales.sale_id');
        $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.customer_id', 'left');
                $this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id = sales.vehicle_id', 'left');
        $this->db->group_by('sales.sale_id');
        if (!empty($search)) {
            // if barcode scanned, explode and search for second term which will be the id
            $pieces = explode(' ',$search);
            if ($valid_receipt && count($pieces) == 2) {
                $this->db->where('sales.sale_id', $pieces[1]);
            } else {
                // open parentheses
                $this->db->where("( last_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR ".
                        "first_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR " .
                        "CONCAT( first_name,' ',last_name ) LIKE '%" . $search . "%')");
                // close parentheses
            }
        }
        if ($only_invoices != 0) {
            $this->db->where('invoice_number <> ', 'NULL');
        }
        return $this->db->get()->num_rows();
    }

    function get_invoice_count()
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where('invoice_number is not null');
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    function get_sale_by_invoice_number($invoice_number)
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where('invoice_number', $invoice_number);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function get_invoice_number_for_year($year='', $start_from = 0) 
    {
        $year = $year == '' ? date('Y') : $year;
        $this->db->select("COUNT( 1 ) AS invoice_number_year", FALSE);
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(sale_time, '%Y' ) = ", $year, FALSE);
        $this->db->where("invoice_number IS NOT ", "NULL", FALSE);
        $result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
        return ($start_from + $result[ 'invoice_number_year']);
    }

    function exists($sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$sale_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return ($query->num_rows()==1);
    }

    function update($sale_data, $sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('sale_id', $sale_id);
        $success = $this->db->update('sales',$sale_data);

        return $success;
    }

    function save ($items,$customer_id,$vehicle_id,$employee_id,$comment,$invoice_number,$payments,$sale_id=false)
    {
        if(count($items)==0)
            return -1;

        $sales_data = array(
            'sale_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'customer_id'=> $this->Customer->exists($customer_id) ? $customer_id : null,
                        'vehicle_id'=> $this->Vehicle->exists($vehicle_id) ? $vehicle_id : null,
            'employee_id'=>$employee_id,
            'comment'=>$comment,
            'invoice_number'=>$invoice_number
        );

        //Run these queries as a transaction, we want to make sure we do all or nothing
        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->insert('sales',$sales_data);
        $sale_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach($payments as $payment_id=>$payment)
        {
            if ( substr( $payment['payment_type'], 0, strlen( $this->lang->line('sales_giftcard') ) ) == $this->lang->line('sales_giftcard') )
            {
                /* We have a gift card and we have to deduct the used value from the total value of the card. */
                $splitpayment = explode( ':', $payment['payment_type'] );
                $cur_giftcard_value = $this->Giftcard->get_giftcard_value( $splitpayment[1] );
                $this->Giftcard->update_giftcard_value( $splitpayment[1], $cur_giftcard_value - $payment['payment_amount'] );
            }

            $sales_payments_data = array
            (
                'sale_id'=>$sale_id,
                'payment_type'=>$payment['payment_type'],
                'payment_amount'=>$payment['payment_amount']
            );
            $this->db->insert('sales_payments',$sales_payments_data);
        }

        foreach($items as $line=>$item)
        {
            $cur_item_info = $this->Item->get_info($item['item_id']);

            $sales_items_data = array
            (
                'sale_id'=>$sale_id,
                'item_id'=>$item['item_id'],
                'line'=>$item['line'],
                'description'=>$item['description'],
                'serialnumber'=>$item['serialnumber'],
                'quantity_purchased'=>$item['quantity'],
                'discount_percent'=>$item['discount'],
                'item_cost_price' => $cur_item_info->cost_price,
                'item_unit_price'=>$item['price'],
                'item_location'=>$item['item_location']
            );

            $this->db->insert('sales_items',$sales_items_data);

            //Update stock quantity
            $item_quantity = $this->Item_quantities->get_item_quantity($item['item_id'], $item['item_location']);       
            $this->Item_quantities->save(array('quantity'=>$item_quantity->quantity - $item['quantity'],
                                              'item_id'=>$item['item_id'],
                                              'location_id'=>$item['item_location']), $item['item_id'], $item['item_location']);


            //Ramel Inventory Tracking
            //Inventory Count Details
            $qty_buy = -$item['quantity'];
            $sale_remarks ='POS '.$sale_id;
            $inv_data = array
            (
                'trans_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'trans_items'=>$item['item_id'],
                'trans_user'=>$employee_id,
                'trans_location'=>$item['item_location'],
                'trans_comment'=>$sale_remarks,
                'trans_inventory'=>$qty_buy
            );
            $this->Inventory->insert($inv_data);
            //------------------------------------Ramel

            $customer = $this->Customer->get_info($customer_id);
            if ($customer_id == -1 or $customer->taxable)
            {
                foreach($this->Item_taxes->get_info($item['item_id']) as $row)
                {
                    $this->db->insert('sales_items_taxes', array(
                        'sale_id'   =>$sale_id,
                        'item_id'   =>$item['item_id'],
                        'line'      =>$item['line'],
                        'name'      =>$row['name'],
                        'percent'   =>$row['percent']
                    ));
                }
            }


                        //------------------------------------Vehi-ras

            $vehicle = $this->Vehicle->get_info($vehicle_id);
            if ($vehicle_id == -1 or $vehicle->taxable)
            {
                foreach($this->Item_taxes->get_info($item['item_id']) as $row)
                {
                    $this->db->insert('sales_items_taxes', array(
                        'sale_id'   =>$sale_id,
                        'item_id'   =>$item['item_id'],
                        'line'      =>$item['line'],
                        'name'      =>$row['name'],
                        'percent'   =>$row['percent']
                    ));
                }
            }

        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return $sale_id;
    }

    function delete_list($sale_ids, $employee_id,$update_inventory=TRUE) 
    {
        $result = TRUE;
        foreach($sale_ids as $sale_id) {
            $result &= $this->delete($sale_id, $employee_id, $update_inventory);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function delete($sale_id,$employee_id,$update_inventory=TRUE) 
    {
        // start a transaction to assure data integrity
        $this->db->trans_start();
        // first delete all payments
        $this->db->delete('sales_payments', array('sale_id' => $sale_id));
        // then delete all taxes on items
        $this->db->delete('sales_items_taxes', array('sale_id' => $sale_id));

        if ($update_inventory) {
            // defect, not all item deletions will be undone??
            // get array with all the items involved in the sale to update the inventory tracking
            $items = $this->get_sale_items($sale_id)->result_array();
            foreach($items as $item) {
                // create query to update inventory tracking
                $inv_data = array
                (
                    'trans_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'trans_items'=>$item['item_id'],
                    'trans_user'=>$employee_id,
                    'trans_comment'=>'Deleting sale ' . $sale_id,
                    'trans_location'=>$item['item_location'],
                    'trans_inventory'=>$item['quantity_purchased']

                );
                // update inventory
                $this->Inventory->insert($inv_data);

                // update quantities
                $this->Item_quantities->change_quantity($item['item_id'],
                    $item['item_location'],
                    $item['quantity_purchased']);
            }
        }

        // delete all items
        $this->db->delete('sales_items', array('sale_id' => $sale_id));
        // delete sale itself
        $this->db->delete('sales', array('sale_id' => $sale_id));

        // execute transaction
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        return $this->db->trans_status();
    }

    function get_sale_items($sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->from('sales_items');
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$sale_id);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function get_sale_payments($sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->from('sales_payments');
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$sale_id);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function get_customer($sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$sale_id);
        return $this->Customer->get_info($this->db->get()->row()->customer_id);
    }

        function get_vehicle($sale_id)
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$sale_id);
        return $this->Vehicle->get_info($this->db->get()->row()->vehicle_id);
    }

    function invoice_number_exists($invoice_number,$sale_id='')
    {
        $this->db->from('sales');
        $this->db->where('invoice_number', $invoice_number);
        if (!empty($sale_id))
        {
            $this->db->where('sale_id !=', $sale_id);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return ($query->num_rows()==1);
    }

    //We create a temp table that allows us to do easy report/sales queries
    public function create_sales_items_temp_table()
    {

        if ($this->config->item('tax_included'))
        {
            $total = "1";
            $subtotal = "(1 - (SUM(1 - 100/(100+percent))))";
            $tax="(SUM(1 - 100/(100+percent)))";
        }
        else
        {
            $tax = "(SUM(percent)/100)";
            $total = "(1+(SUM(percent/100)))";
            $subtotal = "1";
        }

        $this->db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_temp')."
        (SELECT date(sale_time) as sale_date, sale_time, ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').".sale_id, comment,payments.payment_type, item_location, customer_id, vehicle_id, employee_id,
        ".$this->db->dbprefix('items').".item_id, supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_cost_price, item_unit_price, SUM(percent) as item_tax_percent,
        discount_percent, ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*$subtotal,2) as subtotal,
        ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').".line as line, serialnumber, ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').".description as description,
        ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*$total, 2) as total,
        ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*$tax, 2) as tax,
        ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)- (item_cost_price*quantity_purchased), 2) as profit
        FROM ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items')."
        INNER JOIN ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales')." ON  ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').'.sale_id='.$this->db->dbprefix('sales').'.sale_id'."
        INNER JOIN ".$this->db->dbprefix('items')." ON  ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').'.item_id='.$this->db->dbprefix('items').'.item_id'."
        INNER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS sale_payment_amount, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(payment_type SEPARATOR ', ') AS payment_type FROM " .$this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments') . " GROUP BY sale_id) AS payments 
        ON " . $this->db->dbprefix('sales_items') . '.sale_id'. "=" . "payments.sale_id     
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ".$this->db->dbprefix('suppliers')." ON  ".$this->db->dbprefix('items').'.supplier_id='.$this->db->dbprefix('suppliers').'.person_id'."
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ".$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes')." ON  "
        .$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').'.sale_id='.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes').'.sale_id'." and "
        .$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').'.item_id='.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes').'.item_id'." and "
        .$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').'.line='.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes').'.line'."
        GROUP BY sale_id, item_id, line)");

        //Update null item_tax_percents to be 0 instead of null$this->db->where('item_tax_percent IS NULL');
        $this->db->update('sales_items_temp', array('item_tax_percent' => 0));

        //Update null tax to be 0 instead of null
        $this->db->where('tax IS NULL');
        $this->db->update('sales_items_temp', array('tax' => 0));

        //Update null subtotals to be equal to the total as these don't have tax
        $this->db->query('UPDATE '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_temp'). ' SET total=subtotal WHERE total IS NULL');
    }

    public function get_giftcard_value( $giftcardNumber )
    {
        if ( !$this->Giftcard->exists( $this->Giftcard->get_giftcard_id($giftcardNumber)))
            return 0;

        $this->db->from('giftcards');
        $this->db->where('giftcard_number',$giftcardNumber);
        return $this->db->get()->row()->value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why you were joining `ospos_people` twice `LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id 
= ospos_sales.customer_id LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = 
ospos_sales.vehicle_id` if you want to join on multiple condition then use `and` condition instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the table `ospos_people` an alias so that it can be referenced in your JOIN conditions. Otherwise you'll have to tables with the same name in your SQL query.

In your case you have to update your `$this->db->join` calls:

```
$this->db->join('people AS people1', 'people1.person_id = sales.customer_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('people AS people2', 'people2.person_id = sales.vehicle_id', 'left');
```

to get something like:

```
LEFT JOIN ospos_people AS people1 ON people1.person_id = ospos_sales.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN ospos_people AS people2 ON people2.person_id = ospos_sales.vehicle_id
```

**Note:**

You also have the possiblity to use `AND`, `OR`, `IN(...)` in the condition of `LEFT JOIN`s. Please check if you can use something like:

```
$this->db->join('people', 'people.person_id IN (sales.vehicle_id, sales.customer_id)', 'left');
```

Comment: Thank You Mapek :) Where can i find the file location LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = ospos_sales.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = ospos_sales.vehicle_id

Comment: @Job I've updated my answer. Please check the updated `$this->db->join` calls.

Comment: Hi Mapek, After the addition i am getting following error please help ,   A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`IN` (sales.customer_id, sales.vehicle_id) JOIN `ospos_sales_items` ON `ospos_sa' at line 3

Comment: also getting below error A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1052

Column 'first_name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You'll get the `Column 'first_name' in field list is ambiguous` error because you are fetching two fields with the same name `first_name`. Please note that table `people` will only be joined once. Regarding the SQL syntax error you should give me the full generated SQL statement, please.

Answer (score 0):

when you make a join with 1 table more than once you should give alias foreach to be different table to be for example `op1, op2` in the query like this:

```
SELECT ospos_people.first_name, ospos_people.last_name, invoice_number, amount_tendered, sale_time, 
DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date, ospos_sales.sale_id AS 
sale_id, SUM(item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * (1 - discount_percent / 100)) 
AS amount_due FROM (ospos_sales) LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id 
= ospos_sales.customer_id AND  ospos_people.person_id = 
ospos_sales.vehicle_id JOIN ospos_sales_items ON ospos_sales_items.sale_id = 
ospos_sales.sale_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS 
amount_tendered FROM ospos_sales_payments WHERE payment_type <> 'Check' GROUP BY 
sale_id) AS payments ON payments.sale_id = op1.sale_id GROUP BY sale_id 
ORDER BY sale_time desc LIMIT 25
```

also you can refer the table which have a column you select if your 2 tables contain the column with the same name, like this `ospos_people.first_name, ospos_people.last_name`

Comment: Hi Gouda, How can i find the file location of,  LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = ospos_sales.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = ospos_sales.vehicle_id

Comment: No, if you want join with 2 fields you can add **AND** keyword, I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your query on this line

```
LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = ospos_sales.customer_id
LEFT JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_people.person_id = ospos_sales.vehicle_id
```

Table is joined multiple times with the same column.